# Deploying a new web app over existing one

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a new application in visual studio to replace/update an existing Web App on Azure.  The new application is also currently running on Azure as a test app.  If I simply publish the new application using the existing publishing profile, should the new application run smoothly?  Should I check "Remove additional files at destination" in Publish Web Settings so there are no extra files that conflict with the new application?

I suppose I could direct DNS to the new site on azure where it is running, but I cannot add the custom domain to it because it is already in use('The host name www.xxx.com is already assigned to another Azure website:xxx').  Because I can't add the domain, I can't add the ssl certificate.

Publishing new web apps is not something I do often, so I am lookin for the most quick and painless option.

Comment: you could create a deployment slot on your existing app and deploy to that instead. Once it's deployed you can then use the swap feature to switch the instances over and delete the test app or keep it. You just need to make sure the web app setting are the same or set to stay with the deployment slot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this via a deployment slot.

Create a new deployment slot on your web app and deploy to that.

Once you're happy with it, swap the slots so that the new slot becomes the production slot.

Your old version will now be in the "staging" slot (if you called it that).

Here's a link to some docs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Comment: I agree, it sounds like what you want here are deployment slots.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use old publishing profile and publish it over old webapp. It will deploy new application and will remove old one. you can check remove the aditional files.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to switch over change DNS to new Azure Website. That's one of the benefits we get with PAAS. If the Old vs New changes are minor I would suggest to go with the old one. But it seems they are major and you should switch over to the new one.

During the switch over you need to do following things,

1. Take the Old site offline and remove the DNS entry. (simply add a app_offline.html to the site root). Now you are free to set up the DNS for new site.
2. Change DNS and install certificates for the New website. Have a app_offline for this site as well.
3. Do necessary data migrations from old to new. If you use the same db this won't be an issue. Set up system configurations etc. Do whatever it takes to get the site ready.
4. Once the DNS propagation completed it will be pointing to the new site app_offline page. When you are ready with the new website, simply remove the app_offline page and you will be Live.

Switch over most often will involve several tasks. I just mentioned very high level tasks. What you need to do is, you need to create a check list (action list) to make the switch over smooth.

One example would be how do you handle bookmarked URL's in the Old site which may not appear anymore, you need to do permanent redirects. Another would be that how do you map old website URLs' with the New Website URLs if there is a mismatch in the URL formats (Controllers/Actions/Query string).. etc.

You can keep the Old site up for a while in offline mode. If something goes wrong with the new site, it would be easier to Rollback. You need to plan that as well.

In your case things might be not complicated as I explained. But I hope this will give you better idea on what factors you need to consider in a switch over.

I am not sure about the Azure infrastructure you are using. Another seamless way to handle this is to use Azure Traffic Manager and attach both Old and new sites. Advantage is that the DNS is pointed to Traffic manager and you can simply take off old site and get the new one online. This would be ideal if you are planning to use load balancing and have sites in multiple regions.

Here is a link to Azure Friday video for [Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-websites-traffic-manager-and-global-load-balancing/).